# Skip password prompt using sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have script that inputs the list of server ips and ssh using pem key to run commands but some servers have password i want to skip that so that it take the next ip ?
Below is the script:

```
cat privateiptest-ss | while read LINE
do
echo $LINE >> ss-prodcht1.txt
stackname=$LINE
ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication=no" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -t -t -i key.pem ec2-user@$stackname "bash -s" <  sh.sh
done
```

Comment: That won't work. A password request and "normal" output is separate, done by separate scripts or programs. That is due to security issues so that things cannot be automated, just as you try to do ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the option `BatchMode=yes` with ssh, i.e.

```
ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -t -t -i key.pem ec2-user@$stackname "bash -s" <  sh.sh
```

then ssh will never prompt for a password. For servers that do require a password, `ssh` will fail.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i wanted hope this will not break anything ?

Comment: @San's I cannot possibly know if it will break anything, but it will do it will do what you were asking for. You'll just have to test it yourself.